# How can I change a property (TextColor) of a template control based on a Selected Bool Parameter?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a button template that I created. It's based on a Frame and it displays as a square button that when clicked calls a command and also a method in the back end that changes the color for a short time.

The button has a binding parameter ( `Enabled` ), that can be either true of false.

I would like for when this is true that the Label text color is Color.Red and when false it's Color.Green.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<t:ButtonBase xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
                      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
                      xmlns:t="clr-namespace:Japanese.Templates" 
                      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Japanese;assembly=Japanese" 
                      x:Class="Japanese.Templates.SquareButton" x:Name="this" >
    <t:ButtonBase.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding TapCommand, Source={x:Reference this}}" 
                              CommandParameter="{Binding TapCommandParam, Source={x:Reference this}}" 
                              NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Tapped" />
    </t:ButtonBase.GestureRecognizers>
    <Label Text="{Binding Text, Source={x:Reference this}}" x:Name="ButtonLabel" 
           TextColor="{Binding LabelTextColor, Source={x:Reference this}}" />
</t:ButtonBase>
```

and the back-end c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Japanese.Templates
{
    public partial class SquareButton : Frame
    {

    public static readonly BindableProperty EnabledProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Enabled), typeof(bool), typeof(ButtonBase), true);           
    public static readonly BindableProperty LabelTextColorProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(LabelTextColor), typeof(Color), typeof(ButtonBase), default(Color));
    public static readonly BindableProperty TextProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Text), typeof(string), typeof(ButtonBase), default(string));

    public bool Enabled { get { return (bool)GetValue(EnabledProperty); } set { SetValue(EnabledProperty, value); } }
    public Color LabelTextColor { get { return (Color)GetValue(LabelTextColorProperty); } set { SetValue(LabelTextColorProperty, value); } }
    public string Text { get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); } set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); } }

        public SquareButton()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BackgroundColor = (Color)Application.Current.Resources["SquareButtonBackgroundColor"];
        }

        protected async void Tapped(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BackgroundColor = (Color)Application.Current.Resources["CSquareButtonBackgroundColor"];
            await Task.Delay(500);
            BackgroundColor = (Color)Application.Current.Resources["SquareButtonBackgroundColor"];
        }
    }
}
```

Template Use

```
 <template:SquareButton Grid.Column="1" 
     Enabled="{Binding Btns[0].IsSelected}" 
     Text="{Binding Btns[0].Name}" 
     LabelTextColor="{Binding Btns[0].TextColor}" 
     TapCommand="{Binding BtnsBtnCmd }" 
     TapCommandParam="{Binding Btns[0].Name}" />
```

Can anyone give any advice on how I can make the value of the Enabled parameter change the color of the Label between Red and Green.  If possible I would like to do this in the C# back-end code.

Not sure if this helps but I was looking at this event:

public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

Could I somehow detect this in the back-end C# and set the color based on checking the Enabled state when it changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to have all those bindings set up in your custom control (I assume it's a custom control?). It'll just create more code complexity than is required. You also don't need to have two `TapGestureRecognizer`s to the same control (explained further below). Also, it is strongly discouraged to call an element `this`, because `this` is a valid C# reference to the current instance and will lead to problems. So you can get rid of all those:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<t:ButtonBase 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    xmlns:t="clr-namespace:Japanese.Templates" 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Japanese;assembly=Japanese" 
    x:Class="Japanese.Templates.SquareButton" >
    <t:ButtonBase.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer 
            Tapped="Tapped" />
    </t:ButtonBase.GestureRecognizers>
    <Label 
        x:Name="ButtonLabel"
        Text="SomeDefaultText"  
        TextColor="Color.Default" />
</t:ButtonBase>
```

Next, in your `SquareButton` class, you're sort of on the right track with `PropertyChangedEventHandler`. However, that is commonly used with standard properties and must be used when inheriting `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

What you're actually looking for is the `propertyChanged` argument in the `BindableProperty` creation method. This assigns an event so that when the property changes, it will trigger this event. For example:

```cs
// Create your bindable property
public static readonly BindableProperty EnabledProperty = 
    BindableProperty.Create(
        propertyName: nameof(Enabled), 
        returnType: typeof(bool), 
        declaringType: typeof(ButtonBase), 
        defaultValue: true,
        propertyChanged: HandleEnabledPropertyChanged);  // <= The property changed handler!!

// The property
public bool Enabled 
{ 
    get => (bool)GetValue(EnabledProperty); 
    set => SetValue(EnabledProperty, value); 
}

// Create your property-changed handler
private static void HandleEnabledPropertyChanged(
    BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
{
    var control = (SquareButton)bindable;
    if (control != null)
    {
        control.ButtonLabel.TextColor = 
            ((bool)newValue) ? 
            Color.Red : 
            Color.Green; 
    }
}
```

If you want to add additional functionality to the `TapGestureRecognizer`'s `Tapped` event, you'll need to implement another handler for that. For example:

```cs
private EventHandler onTapAdditionalHandler;

// Assignable property (not bindable, but probably can be)
public event EventHandler OnTapAdditionalHandler 
{ 
    add
    {
        // Clear all other handlers subscribed, and add a new one.
        onTapAdditionalHandler = null;
        onTapAdditionalHandler = value;
    }
    remove
    {
        // This will create a warning saying something like "you're not
        // removing the value from the parameter". Only use, If you are
        // 120% sure that you will only have one additional handler.
        onTapAdditionalHandler = null;
    }
}

// Your TapGestureRecognizer Tapped handler
protected void Tapped(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Call this method (no need to await)
    ChangeTheColours();

    // Do the additional handling
    onTapAdditionalHandler?.Invoke(sender, e);
}

private async void ChangeTheColours()
{
    Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        BackgroundColor = (Color)Application.Current.Resources["CSquareButtonBackgroundColor"]);
    await Task.Delay(500); // <= Don't call on the main thread!!
    Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => 
        BackgroundColor = (Color)Application.Current.Resources["SquareButtonBackgroundColor"]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for taking the time to give a good answer to my question.  I will check out everything you have written and let you know if I have any questions. In the mean time I have one small question.  Can you let me know why you used "Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>"   I notice with my code that it does seem to correctly delay the code of 1/2 second so I am wondering what's the reason for adding the "Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>"   Thanks

Comment: @Alan2 No problem! I put `BeginInvokeOnMainThread` because UI-related instructions (like colour changes, visibility, text) should be called on the UI thread. If it works for you, you can take it out. I personally like to be explicit and call them on the UI thread, just in case the method gets called in a background thread and doesn't update the UI.

Comment: Thanks Tom for your quick reply. Couple more questions for you.  Can you explain what does the "add" and "remove" of the OnTapAdditionalHandler?  Also I added a line to my question to show how I use the template.  With your implementation how can/should I specify TapCommand="{Binding BtnsBtnCmd }" TapCommandParam="{Binding Btns[0].Name}" when I use the template?

Comment: For the remove part of OnTapAdditionalHandler the IDE gives me a message saying "the remove accessor does not use the 'value' parameter.  Just wondering if this is okay.  Thanks

Comment: For `add`/`remove`, have a look at [this Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/how-to-implement-interface-events). I'll add a comment in the code to better explain the warning you're seeing.

Comment: You may prefer using `Action` or `Func` instead of `EventHandler`, depending on how you want it to work. That's completely up to you.

Comment: Thanks, I checked out what you said about the add and remove and it all makes sense now.  Thanks for updating the answer with your comments.  Still not sure how I can pass the TapCommand and TapCommandParams to the template however.